# Merge values of the objects properties with the same name into array

Tags: datetime, coffeescript

I have such input:

```
[ { name: 'timezone', value: 'EST' },
  { name: 'interval', value: 'day' },
  { name: 'metrics[]', value: 1},
  { name: 'metrics[]', value: 2} ]
```

As you may already notice - these are parameters from POST request.

What I need to do is to get such output:

```
[ { name: 'timezone', value: 'EST' },
  { name: 'interval', value: 'day' },
  { name: 'metrics[]', value: [ 1, 2 ] },
  { name: 'metrics[]', value: [ 1, 2 ] } ]
```

My code does everything it needs to do, but I'm not sure if it is written in the optimal way, am I overlooking some bugs, etc.

```
arrayify = (params) ->
  arrayifiedParams = {}

  for param in params
    paramName = param.name

    arrayifiedParams[paramName] = arrayifiedParams[paramName] || []
    arrayifiedParams[paramName].push param.value        

  params.map (param) ->
    paramName = param.name
    if arrayifiedParams[paramName].length > 1
      param.value = arrayifiedParams[paramName]
    param
```

Here is the corresponding [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shtirlits/1vykhq32/).

Comment: For your information, next time you wonder if your question title is good or any concern leave a comment, this will reduce "noise" in your question. You did a good enough job on your question title. Welcome to Code Review! I hope you'll have good review!

Comment: Do you need to have duplicate objects?

Comment: @elclanrs nope, I don't. Duplicates should be removed later in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks ok overall. There are perhaps a few CoffeeScript features you can make use of, but nothing major.

However, I don't like that the input array is modified in-place (i.e. the function has side-effects). Other code may hold references to the param objects already, so altering them is potentially dangerous.

I'd rather have the function return a new, separate array with the results, leaving the input array untouched.

Here's a version that does that, and also removes duplicate params (I called it `coalesce` because it sounds fancier):

```
coalesce = (params) ->
  coalesced = {}

  for param in params
    {name, value} = param
    coalesced[name] or= []
    coalesced[name].push value

  for own name, value of coalesced
    value = value[0] if value.length is 1
    {name, value}
```